# My sandisk pendrive shows as 4 gig instead of 8

Tags: windows-7

I can't actually tell how it happened. The only thing i recall is i've been using it to create  bootable usb drive using 'poweriso'  (for installing windows 7) and one day i needed the drive 4 something else so instead of me re-formatting it i opened it in windows explorer and deleted the files on it since then windows labels it as 'CD ROM' instead of it's usual 'removable disk' i opened disk management and saw 3.75Gb unallocated space i tried extending the volume bu to no avail..any help will be appreciated..thanks in advance.

Comment: "To no avail" is not a helpful problem description. What *exactly* did you try to do and what *exactly* went wrong?

Comment: Backup data, delete all existing partitions, create single partition spanning the drive, format, profit.

Comment: I'm going to suggest [`GParted`](https://gparted.org/), but will caution that it's very powerful, so be extra __extra__ sure that you're targeting the correct device!... also I'll warn that the things it'll suggest, Live Boot CDs or USBs, can become an addiction; for me it started with using things like [`System Rescue CD`](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/), but these days I fancy [`Kali`](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install) for fiddling with _stuff_ related to USB... Seemed innocent at the time, only needed Linux for a rescue, then `sudo` found me; lured me from...

Answer (score 0):

If there's unallocated space, that means it's an issue with partitioning. Somehow it got partitioned into only using some of the available space. You can right click the icon in My Computer and format it. Probably you want to use FAT32 if available (not a windows user, so I don't know precisely what options it gives you). Make sure you back up any files on it that you want to keep.